Why does leveldb use a single lock to protect the state?
I saw the follow code in leveldb:
  // State below is protected by mutex_
  port::Mutex mutex_;
  std::atomic<bool> shutting_down_;
  port::CondVar background_work_finished_signal_ GUARDED_BY(mutex_);
  MemTable* mem_;
  MemTable* imm_ GUARDED_BY(mutex_);  // Memtable being compacted
  std::atomic<bool> has_imm_;         // So bg thread can detect non-null imm_
  WritableFile* logfile_;
  uint64_t logfile_number_ GUARDED_BY(mutex_);
  log::Writer* log_;
  uint32_t seed_ GUARDED_BY(mutex_);  // For sampling.

  // Queue of writers.
  std::deque<Writer*> writers_ GUARDED_BY(mutex_);

Why does leveldb use a mutex to protect the writers_ deque (used to store write operations) and the memtable imm_, instead of using a read-write lock to synchronize the write operations? What is the advantage of this approach?

Other than (possibly) compatibility with earlier versions of C++, a queue-reader is not just a "reader" -- they also need to remove the item from the queue.
The general pattern for a reader is like this:

acquire mutex
remove item from queue
release mutex
process item

A shared_mutex would not allow you to remove the item, since you are changing the queue.

What I would like to ask is can a read-write mutex replace the combination of dequewriters_ and mutex mutex_? By this approach, we don't need a channel to store the write task, and we can just use the read-write lock to synchornize the operations.
